# Weird Display Bug with flag interface + Youtube Embeds

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, moderator-tools

Ran into a weird issue this evening with the flag overlays.

[Originally from this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148428/who-is-skidrow#question)

[image]

I don't have Flash installed, but otherwise running Firefox 26.0, Windows 7.

As you can see, the Youtube embed is being rendered in front of the flagged items.

Comment: Should probably cover the name in the screenshot to keep the flags hidden from the rest of us.

Comment: afaik YouTube vids are now showing with HTML5 player, not Flash, so it's not relevant anymore.